# How to update\insert data into a NVARCHAR column using ODBC API

Tags: c++, sql, unicode, odbc, sybase

I am trying to update a Sybase table via Microsofts ODBC API. The following is the basics of the C++ I am trying to execute. In table, TableNameXXX, ColumnNameXXX has a type of  NVARCHAR( 200 ).

```
   SQLWCHAR updateStatement[ 1024 ] = L"UPDATE TableNameXXX SET ColumnNameXXX = N 'Executive Chair эюя' WHERE PKEYXXX = 'VALUE'";
   if( ret = SQLExecDirect( hstmt, ( SQLWCHAR* ) updateStatement, SQL_NTS ) != SQL_SUCCESS )
   {
       // Handle Error
   }
```

The Sybase database has a CatalogCollation of 1252LATIN1, CharSet of windows-1252,  Collation of 1252LATIN1, NcharCharSet of UTF-8 and an NcharCollation of UCA.

Once this works for the Sybase ODBC connection I need to get it to work in various other ODBC drivers for other databases.

The error i get is "[Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'Executive Chair ' on line 1"

If i take out the Unicode characters and remove the N it will update.

Does anyone know how to get this to work? What am I missing?

I wrote a C# .net project using an ODBCConnection to a SQL Server database and am getting "sort of" the same error. I means sort of as this error contains the Unicode Text in the message whereas the Sybase ODBC error has "lost" the unicode.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     using (OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=UnicodeTest;UID=sa;PWD=password")) // ;stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8';CharSet=utf16"
     //using (OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=Conversion;CharSet=utf8")) // ;stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8';CharSet=utf8
     {
        try
        {
           odbc.Open();

           string queryString = "UPDATE TableNameXXX SET ColumnNameXXX = N 'Executive Chair эюя' WHERE PKEYXXX = 'AS000008'";
           System.Console.Out.WriteLine(queryString);
           OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);
           command.Connection = odbc;
           int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           if( result == 1)
           {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success");
           }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     }
  }
```

"ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Executive Chair эюя'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no space between the N and the Unicode enclosed string.

```
"UPDATE TableNameXXX SET ColumnNameXXX = N 'Executive Chair эюя' WHERE PKEYXXX = 'AS000008'"
```

should be

```
"UPDATE TableNameXXX SET ColumnNameXXX = N'Executive Chair эюя' WHERE PKEYXXX = 'AS000008'"
```